# Retrieving user id from one table and inserting it into another table

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Am working on a project where i got two tables
1. users table | (id is primary key)
2. movie table | (movie_id is primary key, id is foreign key)

I want to get user_id from users table and want to insert movie related info when that user has logged in
am using session_variables for this but i don't know if my code is correct or not i have tried following code but didn't get any result.

This is my process.php

```
$errors = [];
$fav = "";
$rank = "";
$rewatched = "";
$status = "";
$recommend = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['fav'])) {
        $errors['fav'] = 'Favourite required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['rank'])) {
        $errors['rank'] = 'Rank required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['rewatched'])) {
        $errors['rewatched'] = 'Rewatched required';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['status'])) {
        $errors['status'] = 'Status required';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['recommend'])) {
        $errors['recommend'] = 'Recommend required';
    }

    $fav = $_POST['fav'];
    $rank = $_POST['rank'];
    $rewatched = $_POST['rewatched'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $recommend = $_POST['recommend'];

    // Select id from users and insert into movie
    if (count($errors) === 0) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM movie WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id']."')";
        $query = "INSERT INTO movie SET fav=?, rank=?, rewatched=?, status=?, recommend=? WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id']."'";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('siiss', $fav, $rank, $rewatched, $status, $recommend);
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        if ($result) {
            $anime_id = $stmt->insert_id;
            $stmt->close();

            $_SESSION['id'] = $movie_id;
            $_SESSION['fav'] = $fav;
            $_SESSION['rank'] = $rank;
            $_SESSION['rewatched'] = $rewatched;
            $_SESSION['status'] = $status;
            $_SESSION['recommend'] = $recommend;
            $_SESSION['message'] = 'Details have been submitted successfully!';
            $_SESSION['type'] = 'alert-success';
        } else {
            $_SESSION['error_msg'] = "Database error: Could not update details";
        }
    }
}
```

In simple words i want to get id from users table and when that particular user has logged in and filled the form related to movie and submitted the results it should be stored in movie table with his/her user id.

Thank you

Comment: You are already storing the User ID in Session Right? Then why you need too query it from DB again? Change `$sql = "SELECT * FROM movie WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['id']."')";` to `$sql = "SELECT * FROM movie WHERE id = $_SESSION['id']";`

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php

// Assuming $_SESSION['id'] is the User ID of the User Who Currently Logged in.

$errors = [];
$fav = "";
$rank = "";
$rewatched = "";
$status = "";
$recommend = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['fav'])) {
        $errors['fav'] = 'Favourite required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['rank'])) {
        $errors['rank'] = 'Rank required';
    }
    if (empty($_POST['rewatched'])) {
        $errors['rewatched'] = 'Rewatched required';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['status'])) {
        $errors['status'] = 'Status required';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['recommend'])) {
        $errors['recommend'] = 'Recommend required';
    }

    $fav = $_POST['fav'];
    $rank = $_POST['rank'];
    $rewatched = $_POST['rewatched'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    $recommend = $_POST['recommend'];
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];

    // Insert into Movie Table
    if (count($errors) === 0) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO movie SET fav=?, rank=?, rewatched=?, status=?, recommend=?, id =?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param('siissi', $fav, $rank, $rewatched, $status, $recommend, $id);
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        if ($result) {
            // If Insertion Successful
        } else {
            // If Something Went Wrong
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code,  when the user submits the form it will capture the form details and store it in movie table with Foreign key as User Id. I assume that `$_SESSION['id']` is the User Id of the currently Logged In User.

Comment: Thank you @ Harish ST for your response  i have tried making changes to my code according to your suggestion but i didn't get any result my database is still blank

Comment: @ Harish ST problem was in my code implementation i have searched for mistakes in code now its working fine  thank you @ Harish ST

Comment: Ok! Glad to hear!

Comment: @ Harish ST my data is being stored in two rows rather than one and why is that ? In one row it stores previously submitted data in other row it stores currently submitted data. when i am refreshing my form a popup box comes and gives following statement   . The page that you're looking for used information that you entered. Returning to that page might cause any action you took to be repeated. Do you want to continue?

Comment: Yes, That's what `INSERT INTO` Query Does. If you want to Change the Existing Row, use `UPDATE` query instead. And Do not forget to mention the `WHERE` Clause.

Comment: each time i refresh my form it automatically stores my previously submitted data in movie table. am not even filling my form and it submits my previous data why is that i don't get it ?

Comment: Open Browser Console and Go to Network Tab. Refresh the page and check the Requests and type of Method.